# Inability to pass an std::time_get.get_date function as argument to another function

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an std::time_get.get_date function as argument to another function.

The reason I want to do this is to also pass other std::time_get functions (that have the same signature) to the other function.

However, I get a compilation error. --EDIT -- Online version follows:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f8df97ff106e9be

```
/** Passing the time_get<char>.get_date function member to a function
*/

#include <locale>           /// time_get<char>
#include <iterator>         /// istreambuf_iterator<char>
#include <ctime>            /// tm
#include <ios>              /// ios_base
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using InIt = istreambuf_iterator<char>;
using IB = ios_base;
using ST = IB::iostate;
using TG = const time_get<char>;
using pGet = InIt (TG::*) (InIt, InIt, IB&, ST&, tm*);

/// Addresses of functions in time_get<char>
auto gd = &TG::get_date;

/// pGet function arguments
InIt frm (cin), til;
ST st;
tm t;

locale loc;                     /// classic "C" locale

TG& tg =                        /// time_get<char> facet
    use_facet<TG> (loc);


void getdtpart(TG& tg, pGet fget)
{
    (tg.*(fget)) (frm, til, cin, st, &t);
}


int main()
{
    getdtpart(tg, gd);

    cout << "Completed" << endl;
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void getdtpart(TG&, pGet)':

main.cpp:34:40: error: invalid conversion from 'TG* {aka const std::__cxx11::time_get<char>*}' to 'TG* {aka std::__cxx11::time_get<char>*}' [-fpermissive]

     (tg.*(fget)) (frm, til, cin, st, &t);
                                        ^

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:40:21: error: cannot convert 'std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (std::__cxx11::time_get<char>::*)(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*) const' to 'pGet {aka std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (std::__cxx11::time_get<char>::*)(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*)}' for argument '2' to 'void getdtpart(TG&, pGet)'

     getdtpart(tg, gd);
                     ^
```

It's clear this is happening because of the presence or absence of 'const', but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is the usage/non-usage of `const` on two places.

First part is `pGet` which should capture the signature of `get_date`, a `const` member function. So add `const` at the end:

```
using pGet = InIt (TG::*) (InIt, InIt, IB&, ST&, tm*) const;
```

The other part is the us of `const` in the TG type, which seems to conflict with the use of `TG` when defining `pGet`.

Factoring that out, and moving some variables into main to avoid a name shadowing, I get this version to compile:

```
/** Passing the time_get<char>.get_date function member to a function
*/

#include <locale>           /// time_get<char>
#include <iterator>         /// istreambuf_iterator<char>
#include <ctime>            /// tm
#include <ios>              /// ios_base
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using InIt = istreambuf_iterator<char>;
using IB = ios_base;
using ST = IB::iostate;
using TG = time_get<char>;
using pGet = InIt (TG::*) (InIt, InIt, IB&, ST&, tm*) const;

/// Addresses of functions in time_get<char>
auto gd = &TG::get_date;

/// pGet function arguments
InIt frm (cin), til;
ST st;
tm t;



void getdtpart(const TG& tg, pGet fget)
{
    (tg.*(fget)) (frm, til, cin, st, &t);
}


int main()
{
   locale loc;                     /// classic "C" locale

   const TG& tg =                        /// time_get<char> facet
       use_facet<TG> (loc);

    getdtpart(tg, gd);

    cout << "Completed" << endl;
}
```